# Iterate the list with float value and then print the same list

Tags: python

I have a list `float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]` with float values.

Where first I am iterating the values of **float_list** and then **multiplying** those values form **2** and in the last i want to print the result in a list where desired result must be this `[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]`

but i am getting a **`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`**
here is my code

**My Code**

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
for i in float_list:
    print([list_num*2 for list_num in i])
```

**Desired Result**

```
[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python-practise/for.py", line 3, in <module>
    print([list_num*2 for list_num in i])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

**Note:** I've also tried to take **i** as string **str(i)** `print([list_num*2 for list_num in str(i)])` but in doing so I got this output in my console

```
['00', '..', '22']
['11', '..', '22']
['11', '..', '55']
['00', '..', '77']
['00', '..', '99']
```

Now I am just stuck Please help me to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing loops and list comprehensions. In your loop, `i` is already a single element of the list, i.e. a number. You should *either* just use a loop...

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
for i in float_list:
    print(i * 2)
```

... *or* a list comprehension:

```
print([i * 2 for i in float_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in float_list:
    print([list_num*2 for list_num in i])
```

i will be a float, because floats are in the list. So you can't iterate over a float, because it's not a list. So "for list_num in i will fail.

Just do this:

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]

print([list_num*2 for list_num in float_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple list (that is not a list of list) , you either use a loop or a list comprehension but not both.

Just delete

```
for i in float_list:
```

and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have two `for` loops. You only need one.

```
>>> float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
>>> new_list = [list_num*2 for list_num in float_list]
>>> print(new_list)
[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]
```

I recommend unpacking it when you print:

```
>>> print(*new_list)
0.4 2.4 3.0 1.4 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner list comprehension causes the error because you are applying a for loop over a single `float` item i.e you cant iterate over a `float` object=>that is what error indicates.

Solution:

use a list comprehension:

```
>>> float_list
[0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
>>> print([list_num*2 for list_num in float_list])
[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]
```

or a loop like this

```
>>> new_list=[]
>>> for i in float_list:
...     new_list+=[i*2]
... 
>>> new_list
[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]
>>>
```

I'd recommend mapping a function to each element of list using `map()`:

```
>>> float_list
[0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
>>> list(map(lambda x:x*2, float_list))
[0.4, 2.4, 3.0, 1.4, 1.8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve it

```
result = [2*i for i in float_list]
print(result)
```

or

```
print([i*2 for i in float_list])
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the task in two steps:

```
# Declare the variables
float_list = [ ] # your present array
float_double_array = [ ] # your to be new array
```

1. Iterate the present list - float_list as below and then multiply by two and then append the result to a float_double_array

   ```
   for index_item in float_list:
       double_item=index_item * 2
       float_double_array.append(double_item)
   ```
2. Now you can use your new float_double_array and it's indexed values as below.

   ```
   for double_floats in float_double_array:
       try:
           print " ".join(double_floats) #handles python 2
       except:
           print (" ".join(double_floats)) #handles python 3
   ```

Finally, any questions,  please ask.

Comment: `print(...)` will work just as well in Python 2, and if you need anything else, just do `from __future__ import print_function`. Apart from that, `try/except` does not protect against `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0):

## Regular Way

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
for i in range(len(float_list)):
   float_list[i]=2*float_list[i]
print(float_list)
```

## Using List Comprehension

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
print([i*2 for i in float_list])
```

## Using higer order function map and lambda

```
float_list = [0.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.7, 0.9]
float_list = list(map(lambda i:i*2,float_list))
print(float_list)
```